# Having trouble meditating long sessions (Physical pain)

Tags: theravada, personal-practice, meditation-practicalities

I like to meditate but because of me being new to it i guess, it is hard for me to meditate more than ten minutes.

I have **no trouble concentrating only got some physical pains**, that occur **during long sessions of meditation.**
**Can someone please help?**

Comment: What kind of meditation are you practicing?

Comment: I am a Buddhist following Theravada meditation practices.(Anapanasathi,Vidarshana)

Comment: For beginner 10 minutes is OK. It will improve gradually.

Comment: What is Vidarshana?

Comment: It is a Meditation taught in Theravada.It is based on the core of buddhism.It tries to change your mind to stay focus in mindfulness at all times. To learn furthermore please refer this link   @Uilium                     http://mahamevnawa.lk/inenglish/

Comment: That sounds like Vipassana.

Comment: Vidarshana is another word for Vipassana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Buddhist meditation is not difficult to learn, although it may take a lifetime to get it right. You can start today with only a few things. You already have a willing mind. Over time, meditation will help you maintain a clear mind and a peaceful outlook on life

1.Get a pillow or soft cushion to sit on.
2.Find a reasonably quiet room or outdoor space.
3.Sit down on the mat or cushion.
4.Let your hands rest one in the other on your lap, palms facing upwards, or place your hands palm up on your knees with your thumb touching your second finger.
5.Close your eyes and start to count your breaths.
6.When thoughts come into your mind, try not to follow them.
7.For a beginner, try to meditate for just a few minutes -- 10 minutes or so is a good start.
8.If you decide to continue with meditation, you may wish to invest in meditation cushions, prayer beads (malas), incense and perhaps some decorations to create a meditation area in your home.
9.if you still can't count your breaths you can listen to flow of water which is available in audio format for 10min,15min,20min, in internet .

I hope this link will help you the most.

http://www.wikihow.com/Practice-Buddhist-Meditation

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism SE! Please note that we generally don't like link-only answers here because if the link goes dead then your answer becomes worthless. Could you please summarize the contents you linked too in your own words?

Comment: @Theravada No problem, have a nice time.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a posture that is too strenuous for you? For example, trying to sit in a lotus position, when you have never done it before?

If so, use an easier posture:

- a chair that allows you to sit in an upright or balanced way,
- folding your legs one in front of the other in the "Burmese posture" with a cushion or folded towel to support your backbone
- a bench

Be careful of pain. Some pain is comes from restlessness and disappears the moment you move, and it is OK- you can even use it and study it, as a way of getting to know dukkha and impermanence. But if the pain endures after your sit (especially if it is in your knees), use an easier posture. Don't try so hard that you injure yourself permanently.

If you are new, and you're doing 10 minutes, and you're doing it every day, then you are starting very well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to relax body and mind. This way you can avoid physical pain and meditate for long hours even without any physical movement. This is by creating mind states which contain Kāya (body) and Citta (mind) [Lahutā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lahut%C4%81) as Chetasikas.

The achievement of this you can practice meditation on the wind [element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mah%C4%81bh%C5%ABta) (expansion contraction feeling tied to inhalation and exhalation process) or passing you consciousness or attention in a zigzag manner though any heavy, gross, solidified or painful areas or just simply being consciously aware of the  sensation in itself. Also developing continuous and recurring attention on a particular object might be of help as this creates bodily pleasantness when closing on the the Jhanas. Also smiling mildly helps as it creates pleasant feeling in the body and mind.